# Matplotlib setup ImportError

Tags: python, git, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to setup Matplotlib for my Angstrom Beaglebone. I followed instructions here: http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html#install-from-git and downloaded matplotlib succesfully.

```
python setup.py install
```

it results with following error. I installed numpy. Why do I get this error? Please help me.

```
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: cannot import name multiarray
```

Answer (score 0):

You need your SO's dependencies i.e. on ubuntu `sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib`

> If you are on debian/ubuntu, you can get all the dependencies required
>   to build matplotlib with: sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib If
>   you are on Fedora/RedHat, you can get all the dependencies required to
>   build matplotlib by first installing yum-builddep and then running: su
>   -c "yum-builddep python-matplotlib" This does not build matplotlib, but it does get all of the build dependencies, which will make
>   building from source easier. If you want to be able to follow the
>   development branch as it changes just replace the last step with (make
>   sure you have setuptools installed):
>
> > python setup.py develop This creates links in the right places and installs the command line script to the appropriate places.
>
> Note Mac OSX users please see the Building on OSX guide. Windows users
>   please see the Building on Windows guide.

Comment: I don't use debian/ubuntu. Instead my system is Angstrom. What should I do in Angstrom?

Comment: I am not very friendly with that distribution but since that dist probably wont have the matplotlib libraries available you have to download the source and install them from source a.k.a python setup.py install